# Right way to design table(s) on Azure Table Storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I am not looking for the code showing how to create a table on Azure Table Storage. I am looking for more like a design guidance.

I have a `WebJob` that runs a long running Process. Each Job has more than one tasks. Each task takes n number of minutes to complete.

In order to have some visibility into the tasks, I am adding one row per task in a table named "`TaskDetails`".

If I also want to save Job related information, is it better to repeat Job details in the `TaskDetails` table or create a separate `Jobs` table and have JobId as one of the field in TaskDetails class.

I do not believe there is a way to Join multiple Azure Tables so i am little confused on the design.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Storage Tables are NOT relational.  SO, no, you can't do joins - there are no relations.  Proper planning for writing and reading to Azure tables is critical.  Really, the number of tables you use to organize your data is irrelevant.  Using Azure tables efficiently requires knowing two values: the **PartitionKey** and the **RowKey**. If you know those two values, you can access any table value quickly and efficiently. If you search by any other fields, you will find yourself iterating over every item in the table and queries will drag on forever.